# How to run a web application project (ASP.NET MVC) within C#, NUnit project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selenium, nunit

I'm building a NUnit test project in Visual Studio (VS) 2022 in order to test an older web site (MVC 4, ASP.NET).  I would like to run a Selenium WebDriver to test the older, MVC 4, web application in VS 2022.  The issue I've run across is that I need to run the site and run the tests at the same time.  In the Selenium WebDriver documentation, I need to give a URL for it to test, but the web site is running in debug in VS 2022.  The code I need to test doesn't have a URL.  How can I run the website from the C# code in the test project, and then run the Selenium WebDriver to test the site?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS Express to debug your web app, you can use following code in test module init (SetUp if i'm not wrong):

```
        Process _iisExpressProcess;

        const string webAppPath = @"..."; // path to web app folder with web.config 
        const string webAppPort = "..."; // port of your web app

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            ErrorDialog = true,
            LoadUserProfile = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Arguments = string.Format("/path:\"{0}\" /port:{1}", webAppPath, webAppPort)
        };
        
        startInfo.FileName = "..."; // absolute path to your iisexpress.exe f.e. C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

        _iisExpressProcess = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        _iisExpressProcess.Start();
```

than your selenium tests methods is going to be be executed.

On test module uninit (TearDown if i'm not wrong) you should terminate iisexpress execution by calling

```
_iisExpressProcess.CloseMainWindow();
```

Update:

If it is critical to test IisExpress shutdown than you should send "Q" key press to Iis Express window and wait till process termination.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public void StopIis()
{
    if (_iisExpressProcess != null)
    {
        // wait Iis express show console window
        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) // 50 * 100 msec
        {
            _iisExpressProcess.Refresh();

            if (_iisExpressProcess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Wait for process window");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        int KEY_Q = 0x51;

        PostMessage(_iisExpressProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, KEY_Q, 0);
        _iisExpressProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```